# How to link a specific line of an espandable list?

Tags: list, hyperlink

I have a page with a collapsible list, with different "subjects" for each lines.
When a subject is clicked then it opens, in the same page, the text related downward.

What I'd like to do is to create a link for each subject, so in another page I can link specific words to subjects I want, and when clicking on them it opens me the list page with the subject already expanded.

Is it achievable?

For instance, this is the list I've got:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_collapsible_symbol

Answer (score 0):

This would be possible if you apply a unique `id` to each element on your page that you would like to link to. For example:

```
<h2 id='my_section'>My Section</h2>
```

This will allow you to link to this `id` with an HTML anchor tag when you include the `id`. As an example, if the above "My Section" was on a page with a path of `/app/teams.html` then you could link to it like this from a different page:

```
<a href="/app/teams.html#my_section">Visit My Section</a>
```

For some more info on how anchor links work to ids, [take a look at the W3 docs for links](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html).

Comment: This is absolutely working, but it only sends me to the exact line of the id that I recall, but I also want the section to be expanded (like it was clicked), that's the problem.

Comment: For that you'll have to get `document.URL` then split on `#` to get the ID that is active. Then use that ID to set the accordion as active.